# Issue in postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have  following query.But TranDate,Amount,Balance are displaying Null. Am new to postgresql. But in sql server values are displaying

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tran
  (TranDate,Amount,Balance) AS
VALUES 
  ('2019-01-01'::date, 1000::int,1000::int), 
  ('2019-01-02', 2000,3000), 
  ('2019-01-03', NULL,3000),
  ('2019-01-04', -500,2500);


  SELECT tran.TranDate,tran.Amount,tran.Balance, date(d) as day
         FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2018-01-01'
                     , timestamp '2018-01-31'
                     , interval  '1 day') d  
             left join  tran  ON  date(tran.TranDate) = d
```

Comment: You are comparing dates in 2019 with timestamps in 2018.  No match is expected.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  thanks ..i will check .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the code using overlapping date ranges, you will see results:

```
SELECT tran.TranDate, tran.Amount, tran.Balance, date(d) as day
FROM generate_series(timestamp '2019-01-01',
                     timestamp '2019-01-31',
                     interval  '1 day'
                    ) d left join
     tran 
     ON  date(tran.TranDate) = d ;
```

You can observe this in [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=29ea934a5d70af18186bc3f75fa1b3a0) db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks ..am  confused date time in postgresql..i thought different issue..